# clang format: disable ordering includes

Tags: c++, include, clang-format

In our C++ project, the order of our includes is regularly changed. This is a problem since we are using some third-party libraries which require a specific include order to avoid problems.

I know, this is bad but we have to deal with it.

Unfortunately, the order of our includes is regularly changed and I suppose that this is due to `clang-format`. I found a [page](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) where you can specify a variable `includeCategories`. 
However, I do not fully understand how it works. 
I simply want to completely disable the ordering of includes. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Have you tried: `SortIncludes: false`?

You can generate a `.clang-format` with preview here: https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/

Comment: That's it, thank you. I need to wait 8 more minutes until I'm able to accept your answer.

Answer (score 31):

To disable sorting for the whole project use `SortIncludes:false` in `.clang-format`.

To disable clang-format only for a specific file region, use `// clang-format off/on` comments.

```
// clang-format off
#include <b.h>
#include <a.h>
#include <c.h>
// clang-format on
#include <d.h>
#include <e.h>
```

Comment: It seems it doesn't work as expected, at least for (old enough) clang-format 10. In particular, includes after `//clang-format on` will never be sorted.

Comment: works on clang-format version 15.0.7

Answer (score 3):

With more recent versions of `clang-format` it seems you need both:

```
IncludeBlocks: Preserve
SortIncludes: Never
```

Answer (score 1):

`SortIncludes: Never` to `.clang-format`

> https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html
>
> SortIncludes [Possible values]: Never , CaseSensitive , CaseInsensitive