# How to correctly disable include sorting by clang-format?

Tags: include, clang-format

This question and answers [clang format: disable ordering includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60334299/clang-format-disable-ordering-includes), indicate that the way to disable sorting of includes by clang-format is to set the following. This works as one may expect.

```yaml
SortIncludes: false
```

However, the documentation (https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) indicates that it should be the following since clang-format 4.

```yaml
SortIncludes: Never
```

But clang-format (v 10.0.0-4ubuntu1) does not grok this

```
$ clang-format -i ./foo.c
YAML:40:15: error: invalid boolean
SortIncludes: Never
              ^~~~~
Error reading ./.clang-format: Invalid argument
```

Is this a bug in the documentation, or have I misunderstood what the docs are saying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version refers only to when the option was added. I had the same error and found out that arguments have changed since version 13.0. Unfortunately, there is no documentation of changes of the arguments between versions.

From clang-format version 4.0 up to 12.0

```
SortIncludes: {true|false}
```

Since version 13.0

```
SortIncludes: {Never|CaseSensitive|CaseInsensitive}
```

Comment: Well this makes reading the documentation a frustrating experience. But thank for explaining!